# Session State in ASP.NET and Accessing website via mobile Devices

Tags: c#, session, mobile, state

I am writing a website in C# and wondering what is the best practice for storing session across Mobile Devices (iphone, droid, etc..)? So if they access my website via a mobile device will it drop a cookie in the phone, or should I use In-Proc, or hidden fields, etc. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session and ViewState both work fine with iPhones and other mobile devices with decent browsers, with or without cookies. The usual caveats on ViewState size and Session misuse apply.

Answer (score 1):

You don´t have any problem using cookies if you develop for smartphones. Maybe developing for old low-end phones, you could use cookie-less session.

You could find some problem in some wap-connections because some proxies remove cookies.